Why is the inside of my egg shell/outside of my cooked egg purple?
My other cooked eggs were all normal. Boiled in regular water with salt, rinsed off with cold water and then put in fridge. None of the other eggs had this and I’ve been boiling eggs the exact same way for years (yay autism) and I have never seen this before. I cannot find anything about it online either.

Duplicate of What would cause the albumen of a hard boiled egg to turn purple??
